# Should I write documentation on first person plural or on third person singular?

Tags: writing-style, programming, third-person

I'm a Spanish computer programmer and I usually write code and documentation in my native language, but lately I'm trying to migrate them to English. The point is this kind of **writing is quite formal (maybe scientific)** and **oriented third person** to read it (and understand it).

I don't know **what should be the best point of view** when I comment the code. I have doubts especially between **first person plural, third person singular** and **if I can skip the subject in these or another cases**.

In practice, I'm trying to describe a piece of code that do something (it will be only read by programmers). These are the options (if you think another better I'd appreciate it):

- 1 . // **It removes the files** => This sounds good to me, but I'm repeating "It" constantly
- 2 . // **Removes the files** => Sometimes used by another people, is this correct? (skip the subject)
- 3 . // **I/We remove the files** => I think this is quite objective (but very common in Spanish, sometimes without the subject)
- 4 . // **Remove the files** => Widely used by English, but I'm not sure if this is grammatically correct (because it's referring to the code (third person singular)). If this is fine, it's supposed to be a second person singular (because of the lack of -s)? An special rule? Maybe an imperative? In that case it would be too much direct and we're explaining the code, not you
- 5 . // **Removing the files** => I think this is wrong. In fact I'm going to do it, but I'm not doing it now

**So, what's the best way to write documentation in an appropriate style (formal and objective)?**

Comment: Are you adding comments to the code (which will be read only by programmers) or writing formal documentation which will have a more general readership?

Comment: Option no. 1 does not work. You cannot use ‘it’ in this manner, though you could use ‘this’. As you say, though, it gets repeated and is not ideal. 3 works, but only in the plural. 2 can work, but sounds somewhat odd (the implied subject is the bit of code being commented). 4 and 5 are the most commonly used, and the ones that sound most natural. Both the infinitive and the gerund have the same meaning of a generic description in this particular context.

Comment: To: Andrew Leach. I've edited it. It will be only read by programmers

Comment: I prefer writing documentation in the second person imperative form.  "Remove the files."

Answer (score 3):

The next person to look at the code will be so grateful that you wrote accurate comments that he/she will not care a bit about small grammar issues. Don't let this sort of thing slow you down at all.

In my own code, I use type 2 (present tense) for declarations and other things that are always true, independent of execution. For example, consider a subroutine that computes the arc tangent.

// Computes the arc tangent of y/x
double atan(x,y);

In the middle of running code, I use the imperative. For example,

// Reject 0/0

// Handle x==0 specially

// Compute sign of result

// Map everything into first quadrant

Hope that helps.